# Filling a Many2Many Field in Python Code in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Good Day! I want create an Automated User Creation when an User Create an Employee Information with only a Portal Access

here is my python code

```
    @api.model
def create(self, vals):
    new_id = super(HrEmployeeExtend, self).write(vals)
    #After Creation of Personnel create a User
    new_loggin_name = new_id.last_name + '_' + str(new_id.employee_id)
    if isinstance(new_id.middle_name, bool):
        new_user_fullname = new_id.first_name + ' ' + new_id.last_name
    else:
        new_user_fullname = new_id.first_name + ' '+ new_id.middle_name + ' ' + new_id.last_name

    model_userinfo = self.env['res.users']

    id_user = model_userinfo.create({
        'name': new_user_fullname,
        'login': new_loggin_name,
        'password':new_loggin_name,
        'groups_id': 1,
        })        
    new_id.user_id = id_user.id
    return new_id
```

I just want to add to a Portal group in the new user

Answer (score 4):

When you create the new user, add them to the portal group. Depending on the permissions of the users running this function you may not need the `sudo()`

```py
user = self.env['res.users'].sudo().create(vals)
self.env.ref('base.group_portal').sudo().write({'users':[(4,user.id)]})
```